# PHP variable is not assigned

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a laravel project.
now I want to access one of my column which is `data`

The `data` colmn contains an array of stuff like `message`, `klant_address`, `reactionPlacer` and more.

```
foreach(Auth::user()->unreadNotifications as $notfiy) {
 {{ $notify->data['klant_address'] }} //This gives an error "variable is not assigned"
}
```

but if i store it first to a variable it does'nt gives an error like this

```
foreach(Auth::user()->unreadNotifications as $notfiy) {
$klantAddress = $notify->data['klant_address']
echo $klantAddress
}
```

Now comes the weirdest part of all
if i do

```
dd($notify->data['klant_address']) <-- this does gives me the signle string return
```

and

```
foreach(Auth::user()->unreadNotifications as $notfiy) {
{{ $notfiy->data['messages'] }} <--- This does output
}
```

does work.

I hope someone can help me or at least explain why this is happened. Because I'm so confused for it.

thanks in advance.

[image: error page]
Error Page

[image: database table]
Database Table

Comment: Please paste the full real error(s).

Comment: It's possible one of the rows of that `unreadNotifications` does not have the attribute `kland_address`, and then the first item in that 'collection` has it. You can step into the loop by constraining with if conditions e.g `if (! array_key_exists('klant_address', $notify->data)) { echo 'over here';  break; }`

Comment: `$notify->data['klant_address']` on it's own does not do anything in PHP. What is it you're trying to do with it? If you *use* the variable in something you've seen yourself it does work.

Comment: You aren't using semicolons (`;`) in your statements, which will lead to inexplicable errors. The compiler craps out and gives the best error it can (in your case an unassigned variable) but that isn't the error you think it is.

Comment: edited the post

Comment: Looks like that not all of the rows has `klant_address` in `data` array.
As per second comment, you can check it with `array_key_exists` function

Comment: Or if you're using php7 you can use Null Coalescing operator to pass default value in case required array parameter is missing. If you want to pass null: `$notify->data['klant_address'] ?? null`. Or if you want to pass empty string: `$notify->data['klant_address'] ?? ''`

Answer (score 0):

Looks more like JSON to me. (Look at the last image)

Try this:

```
{{ $notify->data->klant_address ?? '' }}
```

If that doesn't work, try `{{ json_encode($notify->data)->klant_address ?? '' }}`

(Thrown in ternaries to help with nulls etc.)